# New domain forwarding to search domain

Tags: dns

I set up a new domain with hosting at GoDaddy, and I've edited a basic index.html file and uploaded that to the server, but whenever I try to visit the site, even with different browsers, I am redirected to a search domain with my domain name as a search query. The search provider differs based on the ISP I'm using (I tried both over my home ISP as well as over cellular). I reset my DNS settings, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: It sounds like the DNS has not propagated yet. How long has it been since you "reset your DNS". It can take "upto 48 hours".

Comment: It's been about 12 hours, but I'll keep waiting. Thanks.

Comment: If you do a DNS lookup, do you get the expected results? Try using Google's DNS servers... `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. Try the [OpenDNS](https://cachecheck.opendns.com/) cache and refreshing it if it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a DNS lookup to check a domain names current IP address and DNS record information against multiple name servers located in different parts of the world.

This allows you to check the current state of DNS propagation after having made changes to your domains records.

you can do that on this page. If it's another error, let us know.

www.whatsmydns.net

Comment: Just checked; it must still be propagating, it's about halfway there.